# Trying to modify my CSS Logo with two lines of text in a circle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix my website main logo. The name is Cerebro Design, and I would like to put Cerebro up and Design down, exactly like this:

[image: Cerebro Design]

This is the CSS code I have so far:

```html
<div style="margin:auto;   
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
            border-radius:250px;
            font-size:50px;
            color:#fff;
            line-height:500px;
            text-align:center;
            background:#000;">
  CEREBRO DESIGN
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use that JPG as a logo instead of using CSS? I mean something like `<img src="/logo.jpg">`. Also it's better practice to use spreadsheets than the `style` attribute.

Comment: @bytec0de: Surely you mean stylesheets...

Comment: Why some of you down vote without explaining why? He wants it in css, we can tell him why is best to do it in other ways, but if he doesn't want to I don't see the reasons to down vote.

Comment: @Mr.Web - I didn't downvote but it might have been because they were non-specific as to why they were having trouble with the text and didn't say what they had tried that hadn't worked.

Comment: Thanks!!! sorry for the long reply

Answer (score 1):

```css
#logo{
  margin:auto;   
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border-radius:250px;
  font-size:80px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000;
}
#logo-text{
  margin-left:70px;
  padding-top: 160px;
  max-width:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <div id="logo-text">CEREBRO DESIGN.</div>
</div>
```

Then you just add the correct font and you should be good to go.

As a note, is better to use external or internal (`<style>...</style>`) css than using `style="..."` on an element.

Comment: Sure! Feel free to set my answer as the right one if you feel it is. :D (by clicking the "Check")

Comment: Thank you so much! and sorry for the long reply!

Comment: No problem. Once you have the right answer you are to check it off.

Answer (score 0):

i would use an image for the logo, but if you want to go css way, this could work for you.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpL12s95/)

```
div {
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:500px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div:before, div:after{
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 95px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
}
div:before{
    content: 'CEREBRO';
    top: -10%;
}

div:after{
    content: 'DESIGN.';
    top: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the font you are using? My quick aproach (I'm in a small laptop) would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="cerebro-logo">
    <span class="padding">Cerebro 
        <span class="design-text">Design .</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cerebro-logo {
    margin:auto;   
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:70px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:80px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-align:left;
    background:#000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.padding {
    padding-top: 165px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.design-text {
    letter-spacing: 13px;
}
```

Tip: You can use letter-spacing (for example) to get that spacing effect on the "Design .".

JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/f5qrbbx5/

Comment: Thank you! and sorry for the long reply!

Answer (score 0):

Just add your text, no need to calculate any margin or padding.

```css
.circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 94px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 
.circle:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle > * {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>CEREBRO<br>DESIGN.</span>
</div>
```